# Delete hidden connected face "inside" the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

I have recently been working on an addon called Smart fill, it's basicly a tweaked version of Blenders native fill tool. It combines grid fill,bridge edge loops etc - all on the f key. I am trying to solve some problems and this is one of them. I am trying to get the selection to delete a double face thats being created when i use my command. is there anyway to achieve this in Blender?

If you look at the attached picture and the example at the bottom you can see that i have deleted a face so you can see how it looks inside.The face is connected but i cant remove it with remove doubles.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hidden face is one of types of [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry), hence it can be selected using dedicated operator for this purpose - *Select* > *Non-manifold* (in 3D View header menu).

Note that this doesn't work in Face Selection mode (though **[MeshLint](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint)** addon selects it even in Face Select mode, so you could use it as a reference).